# How to rewrite urls that have an accidental %20 at the end?

Tags: mod-rewrite, iirf

I wound up with a bunch of backlinks to my site that have the correct URL, except there was an accidental trailing space so the links came out with a trailing `%20`, which causes a page not found error.

I tried variations on this:

```
RewriteRule ^/%20 /
```

but it's not working.

Is a `RewriteCond` statement also needed?

Please note this is an IIS 6 server, and these are Wordpress pages that I'm linking to.

Somebody please tell he the secret code to get rid of a `%20` at the end of a URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may **permanently redirect** all concerned urls having a trailing `%20` to the same url without the trailing `%20` by using the following rule:

If you use `UrlDecoding Off` in your `iirf.ini`, use:

```
RedirectRule (.*)%20$ $1 [R=301]
```

Otherwise, IIRF automatically decodes the URL for you before trying to apply the rules. You can therefore use:

```
RedirectRule (.*)\s$ $1 [R=301]
```

---

In order to test this using [`testdriver.exe`](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf20Help/html/6484f8dd-f1e4-4b74-917c-56d63e76d415.htm):

1. Put the above rule in a file called `iirf.ini`.
2. Create a file called `SampleUrls.txt` containing some test URLs, for example:

   ```
   /                      NO REWRITE
   /%20                   REDIRECT 301 /
   /article               NO REWRITE
   /article%20            REDIRECT 301 /article
   ```
3. Call testdriver with a command similar to `%iirfpath%\testdriver.exe -d .`

Please note: testdriver does **not** decode URLs.

You should get an output similar to the following (I removed some newlines):

```
TestDriver: linked with 'Ionic ISAPI Rewriting Filter (IIRF) 2.1.1.28 x64 RELEASE'.
TestDriver: The IIRF library was built on 'Aug  8 2011 02:26:29'

Processing URLs...(.\SampleUrls.txt)

***
Retrieving server variable that is not supported by TestDriver (SCRIPT_NAME)

NO REWRITE '/' ==> --
OK

***
Retrieving server variable that is not supported by TestDriver (SCRIPT_NAME)

REDIRECT 301 '/%20' ==> '/'
OK

***
Retrieving server variable that is not supported by TestDriver (SCRIPT_NAME)

NO REWRITE '/article' ==> --
OK

***
Retrieving server variable that is not supported by TestDriver (SCRIPT_NAME)

REDIRECT 301 '/article%20' ==> '/article'
OK


0 Errors in 4 Total Trials
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I examined the log file, and found it was automatically replacing the %20 with a space, so I modified the above expression slightly, i.e., "RedirectRule (.*)\s$ $1 [R=301]" and it worked great!

Comment: @phil That's because iirf uses by default `UrlDecoding On` - I modified the answer accordingly.